# IE8 does not keep Session Variables

Tags: iis-7, internet-explorer-8, session-state, session-variables

If I host an ASP.NET page with:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Text = HttpContext.Current.Session["a"] == null ? 
                      "null" : 
                      HttpContext.Current.Session["a"].ToString();
    }
    protected void btn_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Text = HttpContext.Current.Cache["a"] == null ? 
                      "null" : 
                      HttpContext.Current.Cache["a"].ToString();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["a"] = "CBA";
            lbl.Text = "assigned Session Variable";

            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(
                    "a", "ABC", null, 
                    DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), TimeSpan.Zero, 
                    CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
        }
    }

</script>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Session</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="read Session" OnClick="btn_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="read Cache" OnClick="btn_Click2" />
        <hr />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

on the first run I do get the `assigned Session Variable` text, but upon click the Session object is always `null`

Id there an option I need to turn on/off to use the normal Session Variables ?

works fine on IIS 6.0 and Cassini (under VS 2008 and 2010).

> I'm starting to be without ideas on what's going on :o(

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

the process of the example page above

[image]

[image]

---

**More tests** shows that this only happens in IE (ie8 in this case), Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome they all give the correct "answer"

[image]

---

> check the [screen cast of the situation](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/showflash.aspx?swf=2010-09-07_1356.swf&h=481&w=841)

Comment: The code appears different than the example. Which click event does "reload" fire? The one dealing with the cache or session?

Comment: yes, I ended up to add a `Cache` button as well just to see how Cache was handled ... it does handles correctly, but I do need the Session variables as I want them per user, not per Application and the data is something that I really don't need to have in cache. **ScreenCast** has the new code (the example code in the beginning of my question)

Comment: I'm having the same issue... does anybody know what could be the problem? The site works just fine on Firefox, but the users (all over the country) use IE8.
The site was working just fine in IE8 until a couple of days ago. I can't find an explanation!

Comment: @alejandro I know an explanation but it doesnt help :( it all started with a **Windows Update** after that, it's stupid, site worked fine and after that, Sessions are not kept. I would point the problem to a DNS/IE thingy as if you change the machine NAME to the IP Address of the server, it all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem may be the underscores in the domain. remove the _ and see if the same thing happens

Comment: Blocking cookies when the host contains underscores is a known issue in IE. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316112

Answer (score 0):

Session ID's are maintained via a locally stored cookie by the browser.

Are you running in some sort of protected mode that prevents IE8 from storing cookies? There should be a red warning icon on the status bar.. something along the "...prevented this site from storing a cookie"

Comment: I already made IE settings to be all "low", added the domain to Trusted Sites, in Advanced Settings I even add the options to show un-trust content... but all I do, I get the same (I do restart IE) :o(