# Session Variables Work in Chrome, Firefox but Fail in IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, session-variables, internet-explorer-11

We recently upgraded a web server to Win2012 (from 2008) and started using ActiveDirectory. The main web site uses an external order form written in C# (ASP.NET 2.0). Everything was working fine in the old server until we migrated. Now I get errors when trying to read Session variables in IE 11 (everything works with other browsers).

This is the error I get with the line causing it:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 



Line 974:  private void WriteTextConfirmation ()
Line 975:  {
Line 976:    string sFolders_OrderForm = Session ["Folders_OrderForm"].ToString ();
Line 977:    string sOrderNumber = Session ["OrderNumber"].ToString ();
Line 978:
```

Source File:  d:\Web Sites\Order Form\SubmitOrder.aspx.cs    Line:  976

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   SubmitOrder.WriteTextConfirmation() in d:\Web Sites\Order Form\SubmitOrder.aspx.cs:976
   SubmitOrder.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Web Sites\Order Form\SubmitOrder.aspx.cs:1189
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427
```

The problem is that the Session variables that are being read are null. They should be set in the Default form and passed for use in the SubmitOrder form. These variables work with FireFox and Chrome but fail in IE. I'm not sure why this would occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem and setting the session state to cookieless in Web.config fixed our problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that it is browser-specific, it would have to be a setting with the browser. Maybe you have cookies turned off?

**Update**
I did some searching, and it looks like it could still be cookie related.

[Session variable empty in iis7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094840/session-variable-empty-in-iis7-application)

> Another common cause of this issue is when the server name contains
>   underscores (e.g. DEV_TEST). Underscores aren't allowed as host names,
>   and could interfere with the ability to set cookies.

This Server Fault question has a few answers saying the same thing:
https://serverfault.com/questions/178733/iis-7-0-does-not-keep-session-variables

And another SO question saying underscores:: [IE8 does not keep Session Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658513/ie8-does-not-keep-session-variables)

More from Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=iis+application+session+variables+IE

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead since it's largely speculating about one of many possible causes.

Comment: @JonathanSampson True. I guess because I couldn't reproduce the situation I felt strange saying, "You have cookies turned off."

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Cookies are set on in IE. I tried created another web site on IIS and copied the site files to it, and it seemed to work sometimes. In the end I placed the site in the main web site and created it as an IIS application. Now it works as expected. I would like to find out why the web site wouldn't work on its own.